# Make interface contain children specified by enum in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, enums, interface

Say I have a dictionary of behaviours, in my specific case it's a dictionary of sorting functions.

I want to pass one to another function that goes ahead and actually performs the sort. To do that, I declare an Enum containing possible sorting methods. In my specific case I have alphabetical, counter alphabetical, oldest, newest and a whole stack of others. So if I want to export a set of functions, I want to have an object extending this enum. However, from some quick code tests, I wasn't able to find any sort of method of constricting an object to an enum and still specifying the fact that each element inside this enum is a function.

Take this as an example:

```
enum sorts {
    alphabetical,
    counterAlphabetical,
    oldest,
    newes
    ...
}
```

And I have an object defining these functions:

```
const SortingFunctions: sorts = {
    alphabetical: (i: SampleObject, j: SampleObject): SampleObject => // implement function
}
```

Then I get an error:

> TS2322: Type '{ alphabetical: (i: SampleObject, j:SampleObject) => SampleObject }' is not assignable to type 'SampleObjectFilter'.

So if I want to tell typescript that every entry in that enum follows a particular signature, I can either get the user to pass the correct item from the `SortingFunctions` object (the one with the implementations) or I can get a resolver function to resolve the correct sorting function based off of the input value which was originally specified over the enum.

```
function sort(sortingMethod: sorts): SampleObject[] {
    return SortingFunctions[sortingMethod](SampleObjects); // Some Sorting algorithm implementation, that's irrelevant
}
```

Which I think is the preferred method of declaring an object as using variable declaration method would result in the types not being explicitly defined.

So anyway, I tried declaring the `SortingFunctions` object as an object containing keys of the `sorts` enum like so:

```
const SortingFunctions: {
    [Algorithm as keyof sorts: string]: (i: SampleObject, j: SampleObject) => SampleObject
} = {
    // implementations
};
```

but of course that threw a syntax error.

Anyway, the question is whether it is possible to use an enum to declare properties of a dictionary of functions in such a way that the compiler knows to reference that enum should that usage come up.

Sorry for the word count.
I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
enum SortMethod {
    alphabetical,
    counterAlphabetical,
    // oldest,
    // newes
};

type SortFN<T> = (a: T, b: T) => T;
type SortMethods<T> = Record<SortMethod, SortFN<T>>

const numericSortMethods: SortMethods<number> = {
    [SortMethod.alphabetical]: (a, b) => {
        return a > b ? a : b
    },
    [SortMethod.counterAlphabetical]: (a, b) => {
        return b > a ? a : b
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, yes that sort of did work, however I'm not entirely sure what `Record` is and as a result, I'm getting a type error stating that `SortFn` is not assignable to type `Record<SortMethod, SortFN<number>>`

Comment: `Record<A, B>` is basicially `{ [key: A]: B }`

Comment: So I would have to declare that as well?

Comment: I don't understand what you have the problem with. This is how you can execute the sorting method based on `SortMethod` enum: `numericSortMethods[SortMethod.alphabetical](1, 3)`.

Comment: I Did some digging and found the solution to this weird syntax error: Turns out all I had to do was declare each member.